# Update Javascript Object, nested Data - insert only if not updateable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, insert, lodash

Let's say i have the following data

```
var obj = {
  test: 'somedata',
  scores: [
    {
      "points":99, 
      "id":"x12"
    },
    {
      "points":21, 
      "id":"x13"
    }
  ],
  sites: [
    {
      "exercises":21, 
      "sid":"s12"
    },
    {
      "exercises":23, 
      "sid":"s11"
    }
  ],
  history: {
    key: 'value',
    commits: [
      {
         id: 1,
         value: 'thank you'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that `scores` and `sites` contain arrays with unique elements based on `id` in `scores` and based on `sid` in `sites`. I want a function that does the following magic:

```
//will **update** obj.test to 'newdata' and return {test:'newdata'}
magicUpdate(obj, {test:'newdata'}) 

//will **insert** obj.newkey with with value 'value' and return {newkey: 'value'}
magicUpdate(obj, {newkey: 'value'})

//will do nothing and return {}
magicUpdate(obj, {scores: []})

//will **update** scores[0] and return {scores:[{points:3, id: "x12"}]}, as id "x12" is already in the array at index 0
magicUpdate(obj, {scores:[{points:3, id: "x12"}])

//will **insert** {points:3, id: "x14"} into obj.scores and return {scores:[{points:3, id: "x14"}]}
magicUpdate(obj, {scores:[{points:3, id: "x14"}]})

//will **update** sites[0] and return {sites:[{exercises:22, sid: "s12"}]}, as id "s12" is already in the array at index 0
magicUpdate(obj, {sites:[{exercises:22, sid: "s12"}])

//will **insert** {exercises:10, sid: "s14"} into obj.sites and return {sites:[{exercises:10, sid: "s14"}]}
magicUpdate(obj, {sites:[{exercises:10, sid: "s14"}]})

//and also be recursive ...
//will **update** obj.history.commits[0]
magicUpdate(obj, {'history.commits': [{id:1, value: 'changed'}]});
```

I have seen [*.update*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#update) doing the recursion, but only if one is passing the `path` which should be determined automatically. Then there is [.merge](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.4/lodash.js#L13339) which internally uses [_.baseMerge](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.4/lodash.js#L3590) and comes really close to what i need though I do not understand the signature of the function.

```
_.merge(
{scores:[{id: 12, points:10}, {id: 13, points:10}]}, 
{scores:[{id: 14, points:10}, {id: 15, points:10}]}
) 
// returns {scores:[{id: 14, points:10}, {id: 15, points:10}]} not the fully merged array
```

Can someone point me to a good direction or has achieved similar things with lodash?

Comment: And what did you try so far ?

Comment: I have tried writing my own function which ended not good when I noticed that I also need recursion. Then I found the lodash functions above and thought about someone might have had the same issue before.

Comment: I noticed merge working perfectly for Objects and nested Objects. Maybe i just try to transform my data structure from `scores : [{id: s1, points:2},...]` to `scores:{s1:{points:2},...}`

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/r0507fyh/](https://jsfiddle.net/r0507fyh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a solution which is recursive and quite performant. [See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r0507fyh/3)

```
function mergeRecursive(obj1, obj2) {
  if (obj1.constructor == Array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
      if (obj1[i].id == obj2.id) {
        obj1[i] = obj2;
        return obj1;
      }
    }
    obj1.push(obj2);
    return obj1;
  }
  for (var p in obj2) {
    // Property in destination object set; update its value.
    if (obj2[p].constructor == Array) {
      obj2[p].forEach(function(arrayElement) {
        obj1[p] = MergeRecursive(obj1[p], arrayElement);
      });
    } else if (obj2[p].constructor == Object) {
      obj1[p] = MergeRecursive(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
    } else {
      obj1[p] = obj2[p];
    }
  }
  return obj1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `magicUpdate` function you mention in your post could be achieved using lodash functions indeed.

For this implementation, I've used mostly [_ .get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#get), [_ .set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#set) and [_ .unionWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#unionWith) though I'm sure it could have been achieved using some others:

```
// src will be mutated. For simplicity's sake, obj is an object with only one property that represents the changes to make to src
function magicUpdate(src, obj) {
  var key = _.first(_.keys(obj)),
    value = _.get(obj, key),
    srcValue = _.get(src, key),
    comparator = function(a, b) {
      var idKey = _.isUndefined(a.id) ? 'sid' : 'id';
      return a[idKey] === b[idKey];
    }

  if (_.isArray(srcValue)) {
    value = _.unionWith(value, srcValue, comparator);
  }

  return _.set(src, key, value);
}
```

As you may have noticed looking at the code, the return type is the mutated object and not what you're asking. I wasn't really sure what you wanted as a return value.

Anyway, Lodash doesn't have a built-in object difference function so it'd be necessary to develop something like that in case you wanted the difference between the old object and the modified one (you'd also have to [_ .clone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#clone) the object first to have a copy and be able to compare).

The idea of the function I present is to try to get the key of obj (it's the key we want to modify in `src`) and check if it exists and is an array. If so, we just add the two arrays, updating those in `src` that have the same `id` in `obj`. Due to the fact that `sites`, `scores` and `history` had `id` and `sid` I had to add some more logic to the comparator of the `_.unionWith` function.

If `key` doesn't exist or isn't an array, we just set it in `src`.

Here you have the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy1dtvjg/) in case you want to play with it. Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

My first solution was intended for one property updated at a time. However, it seems that is possible to update more than one at the same time.

One quick solution could be to iterate over the object with the updates and update one property at a time.

```
function updateProperty(src, obj) {
  var key = _.first(_.keys(obj)),
    value = _.get(obj, key),
    srcValue = _.get(src, key),
    comparator = function(a, b) {
      var idKey = _.isUndefined(a.id) ? 'sid' : 'id';
      return a[idKey] === b[idKey];
    }

  if (_.isArray(srcValue)) {
    value = _.unionWith(value, srcValue, comparator);
  }

  return _.set(src, key, value);
}

function magicUpdate(obj, src) {
  _.forEach(src, function(value, key) {
      updateProperty(obj, _.pick(src, key));
  });
  return obj;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyf3hbe1/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Unfortunately it does not work, when one is trying to set more than one value at once (which I have to admit was not covered by my examples above, but now is). See here: [https://jsfiddle.net/qyf3hbe1/](https://jsfiddle.net/qyf3hbe1/). I came up with the following solution: [https://jsfiddle.net/r0507fyh/](https://jsfiddle.net/r0507fyh/)

Comment: @niklas Thanks! I've updated the answer with a possible solution to the problem: using the current method, update one property at a time. It might work! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out that the performance (due to many loops of your solution is ~ 10 times slower than a custom function I programmed. See here https://jsfiddle.net/r0507fyh/3/